# AWS CloudFormation stack stuck in the state UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I wanted to update my stack. The stack failed with error Function not found: arn:aws:lambda....
And stack in status UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS more than 5 hours. How do I stop this process?

Comment: Contact AWS support

Comment: I had to purchase AWS support due to the similar problem. It actually proved very helpful over the time. So I don't regret the costs, it was well worth it.

Answer (score 4):

If you deleted the function outside of CloudFormation, then you can manually create a new function of the **same name**. This sometimes helps.

You can also wait till the rollback timeouts. And it usually does after a while, but the time varies.

Another reason why it gets stuck in this state could be due to nested stacks:

- [Nested Stacks are Stuck in UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS, UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS, or UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/troubleshooting.html)

In this case a recommended option is indeed to contact support:

> To fix the stack, contact **AWS customer support**.

Recent **AWS blog post** also describes the issue and possible solutions:

- [Why is my AWS CloudFormation stack stuck in the state CREATE_IN_PROGRESS, UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS, UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS, or DELETE_IN_PROGRESS?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-stack-stuck-progress/)

Regarding the time to wait, the **timeout varies**:

> In most situations, you must wait for your AWS CloudFormation stack to time out. The **timeout length varies**, and is based on the individual resource stabilization requirements that AWS CloudFormation waits for to reach the desired state.

Comment: In the nested stack resource AWS::DynamoDB::Table stucks in UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS.

Comment: how many rollback timeouts are there? More than 6 hours have passed

Comment: @DarkinRall Hi. I see you actually have the nested stack (your question does not mention this). Was the lambda part of the nested stack? You can still create it manually and see how it goes. But as per docs, in the meantime you can contact support and see what they say.

Comment: Yes, lambda inside nested stack. I created lambda, but stack is stuck.

Comment: @DarkinRall Its a common issue, thus the page from the AWS docs which I linked describes it. I recommend to have a read. As I wrote in my answer they also advise to contact support. They maybe the only one to fix that.

Comment: @DarkinRall I found new link as well here. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

In our case, we have mistakenly passed wrong image name to cloudformation template. After realising the mistake, we tried to stop the stack update, which made the stack stuck for forever in UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS status. SO during ECS service creation it got stuck.
Solution:

1. in Stack event check in which step is in progress. (our case ECS service update)
2. Go to ECS service.
3. Click on Update service.
4. Choose older task definitions.
5. And Update.

Your Task definition is reset to previous version. And roll back will complete successfully.

Answer (score 1):

## If your CloudFormation uses ECS:

For me, this happened because I had a rule for ECR images to be deleted after 1 day of inactivity. So when a CloudFormation update failed, ECS tried to rollback to an image that wasn't there anymore.

I manually deleted the ECS service (via AWS web UI) and waited ~1 hour for it to timeout. Then I could delete the CloudFormation stack.

This is why you test deploys in staging first!

Comment: Going through the same thing. 

I imagine that everyone who uses Cloudformation and ECS falls into this trap.

I just pushed an image with the same tag, and now hoping that this resolves the issue.

Comment: or update the desired_count to 0